# COM interop, C#, Visual Studio 2010 -> embed interop types

Tags: c#, delphi, com, interop

My C# program accesses SAP via Nco3 (sapnco.dll). This program also needs to work with Delphi. Some of my methods return types from the sapnco.dll:

```
public void IRfcTable table(...) { ... }
```

in Delphi this method shows up as

```
function table(...): IUnknown { ... }
```

I suppose this `IUnknown` is because my TLB does not include the sapnco.dll. I tried "Embed Interop Types = true" in Visual Studio, but then this error occurs:

> Error Interoptypen aus Assembly "C:\..." können nicht eingebettet werden, weil das ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute-Attribut oder das PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute-Attribut fehlt.    c:...\sapnco.dll
>
> (Interop Types could not be embedded because some attributes are missing).

Is this the right way? If so, where to put these attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sapnco.dll is a .NET dll, so it is not exposed to COM, so you cannot directly use this types in a COM environment. The solution to your problem is to create a library to wrap the sapnco.dll in COM exposed classes:

As an example:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IComRfcTable
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class ComRfcTable : IComRfcTable
{
    private _rfcTable; // object to wrap
    public ComRfcTable(IRfcTable rfcTable)
    {
        _rfcTable = rfcTable
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _rfcTable.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Then your method must be implemented like:

```
 public IComRfcTable table(...) { ... }
```

Comment: Your class should implement interface. "public class ComRfcTable : IComRfcTable"